# Where does Intellij IDE store a console program written in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a simple program

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

It compiled and ran fine in Intellij IDE on ubuntu 22.04 but I cannot find the executable anywhere.

Comment: `find . -name *.class` in your project folder. Depending on your build tool and project configuration, it could be something like `build/classes/kotlin` or somewhere different entirely.

Comment: What build system are you using? Gradle/Maven/IntelliJ? What platform are you targeting? JVM/Native/JS?

Comment: I found it in `/home/xx/IdeaProjects/hellokotlin/build/classes/kotlin/main/`. It is `MainKt.class` but It when I ran it with `java MainKt.class` it threw this error `Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt.class`. It is a gradle project for the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin is a JVM language, so by default (unless you use something like Kotlin Native), your code will get compiled to Java classes (files with a `.class` extension).

They will be generated somewhere inside your project folder, typically under either `target` or `out` or `build` depending on what build system you are using (Maven, Gradle etc.)